# How to use serilog with latest asp.net 5?

Tags: asp.net

If I have both

```
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-*,
```

and

```
    "Serilog.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-*"
```

in my `project.json`, then I'm getting the following conflict:

> The type ILoggerFactory exists in both
>   Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Abstractions and
>   Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Interfaces
>
> The type ILogger exists in both
>   Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Abstractions and
>   Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Interfaces

Comment: I'm having the same issues.  I believe Serilog needs to work on an update to this issues.  Happens for me with ASPNET5 beta5.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have mixed old and new packages in your project.json.
Take a look at this [announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/14), you can see that in aspnet 1.0.0-beta5 some packages where renamed. So,for example, Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console depends on OLD Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Interfaces and Serilog.Framework.Logging depends on NEW Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Abstractions, look at your project.lock.json for dependency details.
Try to update your packages to beta6 version in project.json, also do not forget to `dnvm upgrade` dnx.
I hope it will help you )
Thanks